# Force scaling when printing an alien paper size

Tags: ubuntu, printing, cups

Is there any way to automatically rescale a print job to a paper size supported by the printer even if the application printing has used a different paper size?

I have lot of problems with different clients trying to print US Letter on a printer with A4 paper. It is very easy to miss setting up the correct paper size and then the printer job fails and the printer has to be physically accessed to reset the error. Also any jobs submitted after the error is silently ignored resulting in missing printouts.

I am using Ubuntu and CUPS together with a Konica Minolta network printer.

Ideal CUPS would silently accept any paper size and rescale it to fit into A4 paper and send it to the printer. Is this possible somehow?

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it's possible - because I have the opposite problem.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want automatic scaling and rather have an error instead?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting automatic scaling (from legal to letter) when I'd rather prompt the user to insert the correct paper size.

Comment: Interesting... Are you using CUPS? What printer?

Comment: Yes, I'm using CUPS.  The main printer we're testing with is a Lexmark T640.  I found a workaround using `-o raw` and PJL commands, but I'd prefer a way to do it with CUPS options (in case we ever need to print to a non-PJL printer).

Comment: Do you run Ubuntu or some other Linux setup?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2054/discussion-between-user46971-and-anders-hansson)

Answer (score 2):

Something that worked for me was going to the CUPS website for the printer (http://localhost:631/printers) and choosing the printer. Then under maintenance choose modify printer. Under that page should be an option for scaling. If not, try the manufacturers PPD file or use Acrobat Reader which scales pages automatically. There probably is an extremely complicated ghostscript command for this but I have yet to figure it out.

Comment: I'll try to test this out and let you know how it turns out! Thanks!

Comment: Did this actually work for you? I know it's 10+ years later...